# PDO insert not working correctly

Tags: php

When I login it's suppose to insert, but instead does nothing.. On my register php it inserts data to accounts, but when i insert data into online it won't work..
PS- I'm new to PDO so I don't know what i'm doing wrong

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['users']) != ""){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">','index();','</script>';
}

include('../php/dbConnect.php');
    $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE username = ?';
    $queryprepare = $conn->prepare($query);
    $queryprepare->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $queryprepare->execute();

    $row = $queryprepare->fetch();
    if($row['password'] == md5($password))
    {
      $_SESSION['online'] = true;
      $_SESSION['users'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
      $_SESSION['age'] = $row['age'];
      $_SESSION['image'] = $row['image'];

      $check_row = 'SELECT * FROM `online` WHERE username = ?';
      $check_row_fetch = $conn->prepare($check_row);
      $check_row_fetch->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $check_row_fetch->execute();

      $number_of_rows = $check_row_fetch->rowCount();
      if($number_of_rows != 0) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">','redirect();','</script>';
      }
      else{
        $online_insert = 'INSERT INTO online (username, name, age, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $online_insert_fetch = $conn->prepare($online_insert);
        $online_insert_fetch->bindParam(1, $SESSION['users'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $online_insert_fetch->bindParam(2, $SESSION['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $online_insert_fetch->bindParam(3, $SESSION['age'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $online_insert_fetch->bindParam(4, $SESSION['image'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $online_insert_fetch->execute();

          echo '<script type="text/javascript">','redirect();','</script>';
      }
    }
    else{
        echo("Wrong Credentials");
 }
?>
```

Comment: MD5 is no longer considered safe for passwords. Use PHP's built in functions to handle password hashing.

Comment: and this `if(isset($_SESSION['users']) != "")` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I've tried everything to get insert to work, but no luck...

Comment: It's not jumping out at me, either.  My suggestion would be to abstract out the database calls, so that you can test it by itself.  ie, create a Database class with methods for find, insert, update, delete, etc.  Then in your login script you just add in the known working class; for example, `$db = new Database; $db->insert(array($user,$name,$age,$image));`  This way you eliminate whatever error we're missing.  And, you'll get reusable code, too.